# I can't get the JSON value by Python3.9

Tags: python-3.x

Following code works well(displays 'value1').

```
import base64
import json
import zlib
import datetime
import os
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    value1 = '{"mail": "dummy1@google.co.jp", "ts": "1663057817.928149"} '
    print(value1)
```

I want to get only the value. So I changed the code as bellow.

```
    print(value1["mail"])
```

But the following error occurred. I can't get the value.

```
  "errorMessage": "string indices must be integers",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "fc8c130a-d3a2-4c16-81c7-4f72647f072a",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    print(value1[\"mail\"])\n"
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong is exactly what it tells you: string indices must be integers, you're using a string (`"mail"`). If you're expecting a dictionary, don't write a string (or maybe parse the JSON it represents, but that's pointless in the literal case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `value1` its a string not a dictionary/json-object. You'll need to deserialize it first using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) like so:

```py
print(json.loads(value1)['mail'])
```

Comment: Hello game0ver,

I'm sorry for late reply.
The problem is solved thanks to your advise.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I've been of some help :)